# Ruby on Rails inheritance?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I've seen a bunch of rails "inheritance" models but any of them makes sense for me
What is the right way to use inheritance in rails?

Model Person with name, address
Model User > Person, with all of the attributes of Person plus user and password

thanks!

Comment: Why can't you just add name and address directly to User?

Comment: Do you talk about [STI - Single Table Inheritance](https://devblast.com/b/single-table-inheritance-with-rails-4-part-1) ?